# How do I make Firefox my default pdf viewer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, pdf, pdf-reader

Whenever I double click a pdf file, it should open in firefox. I can do it with Google Chrome but not Firefox. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced same problem. In Windows 10's default apps section, Firefox is not even listed for PDF file type. The below steps helped me:

1. Right Click on pdf file
2. Choose "Open With"
3. "Choose Another App", Check "Always use this app to open .pdf files"
4. Select firefox (if not listed, open from firefox.exe locatin)
5. PDF opens with Firefox, from now on

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on any pdf file and click open with and choose default program which you want.